# How get a list with all items beginning with request param from optional stream

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, stream

I want write a method where when you post a parameter fooName it returns a list with all values that start with the given parameter. I wrote such a function but unfortunately it returns a list with only one, first found value that starts with fooName. How to return a list with all matching values?

```
  @GetMapping    
    @ResponseBody
        public List<Stream> getAllStreams(@RequestParam("fooName") String fooName){
            var optionalStream = streamService.getAllStreams().stream()
                    .filter(str -> str.getFooName().startsWith(fooName)).findAny();
            if (optionalStream.isPresent()) {
                List<Stream> targetLongList = optionalStream.stream()
                        .filter(str -> str.getFooName().startsWith(fooName))
                        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
                return targetLongList;
            }
                return null;
        }
```

My getAllStreams look like that

```
[
    {
        "value": "c30",
        "fooName": "example2"
    },
    {
        "value": "90",
        "fooName": "example1"
    }
]
```

and when I post example I only gets

```
[
    {
        "value": "c30",
        "fooName": "example2"
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are doing it to two times. Also findAny will only give you one item

You could just do it with one line

```
return streamService.getAllStreams().stream()
        .filter(str -> str.getFooName().startsWith(fooName)).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: I used findAny to be sure if there is a component with that fooName and I thought I must make new List with that elements